# Homomorphism between symmetric group and general linear group of order n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am having trouble proving the following:

> Show that $f: S_n \to GL_n(\mathbb{R}),\;\: f(x)=A_x$ is a homomorphism where $A_x$ is the permutation matrix associated with $x$.

$S_n$ is the symmetric group and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the general linear group of order $n$.

Comment: What have you tried? There is not really any trick here, it is just a matter of applying the definitions.

Comment: I tried f(xy)=Ax * Ay.This is the definition of homomorphism and we have to show that this map satisfies this.But I am having trouble computing Ax * Ay.I don't know what I am missing here

Comment: One way is to note that those permutation matrices are uniquely determined by what they do to the standard basis.

Comment: Note that you use order in two different ways in your post. The first regards the number of elements of the group while the second refers to the dimension of the space on which $GL_n$ acts.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand how that would solve the problem.
The way to approach these problems(that i know of) is to start with f(xy)=Axy and then solve it to show that it is equal to    Ax * Ay.Can you guide me on those lines?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to show. One way to do that is to show that they are equal is that they permute the standard basis in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

I can explicitly show you how to do this for $S_3$:

$e \to I$, the 3x3 identity matrix.

$(1\ 2) \to \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

$(1\ 3) \to \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

$(2\ 3) \to \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$

$(1\ 2\ 3) \to \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$

$(1\ 3\ 2) \to \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

This map assumes you multiply permutations "composition-wise" (right-to left). If you do it the other way, use the transposes.

Answer (score 1):

For an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and a permutation $\sigma$, let $\sigma A$
denote the matrix obtained by using $\sigma$ to permute the rows of $A$. Then
$A_{\sigma}=\sigma I$ and we have to show that $A_{\sigma}A_{\tau}%
=A_{\sigma\tau}$.

Explicitly, if $A=(a_{ij})$, then $\sigma A=(a_{ij}^{\prime})$ with
$a_{ij}^{\prime}=a_{\sigma^{-1}(i)j}$. Use this to show that $(\sigma
A)B=\sigma(AB)$. Now
$A_{\sigma}A_{\tau}=(\sigma I)(\tau I)=\sigma(I\cdot\tau I)=\sigma(\tau
I)=A_{\sigma\tau}.$