# $S_n$ is isomorphic the permutations of the identity matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> Prove that the set of permutations $S_n$ is isomorphic to the group of invertible square matrices of order $n$ where each row has $n-1$ zeros and $1$ in one place.

This is very intuitive to me, as I defined the following isomorphism, except that I could not prove that it is an isomorphism:

> I'll define $t \colon S_n \to G$, where $G$ is the group of invertible square matrices of ordner $n$ where each row has $n-1$ zeros and $1$ in one place. I'll define it as such: $t(\sigma)$ will equal the matrix where we permute the columns of the identity matrix of order $n$ according to $\sigma$. That is, if $\sigma (i) = k$ then we will switch between column $i$ and $k$.

However, I am harding a hard time proving that it is an isomorphism. Help would be appreciated

Comment: I do not understand... what does it mean to say "matrix where we permute the columns according to $\sigma$"... For $n=3$, can you tell me what is image of $(1~2~3)$

Comment: I have edited my question, please see if it answers your question now

Comment: Use [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457972/homomorphism-between-symmetric-group-and-general-linear-group-of-order-n). It gives an explicit isomorphism for $n=3$, and this is generalised.

Comment: due to my inability to grasp it quickly, I am still unable to understand your map... can you please give one example

Comment: @kklm please see the question Dietrich pointed to. This is exactly how I defined my isomorphism. All I am having a hard time with is proving formally that it is an isomorphism!

Answer (score 0):

If $\sigma \in S_n$ then by your definition  $t(\sigma)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $1$ appears as $(\sigma(i),i)th $ entries and zero elsewhere.

Now look at $t(\sigma_1)t(\sigma_2)$. The $(\sigma_1\sigma_2(i),i)th$ entry is obtained by taking the inner product of $\sigma_1\sigma_2 (i)th$ row of $t(\sigma_1)$ and the $i~th$ column of $t(\sigma_2)$. Now one can easily see that $t(\sigma_1 \sigma_2)=t(\sigma_1)t(\sigma_2)$. This takes care of the homomorphism part of the argument. Injectivity and surjectivity are forced by the definition of your map $t$.